# Vertically aligning elements with CSS

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have an element that's 60px tall that has other elements like an image and a couple of spans inside of it and I'm having trouble getting them to align vertically inside the 60px high element. Here's the mockup and CSS:

```
<div class="member">
    <img src="images/pic.png" alt="John Smiths's Profile Picture" class="pic">
    <span class="name"><a href="">John Smith</a></span>
    <span class="skills">PHP, MySQL, Javascript, C#, Java</span>
</div>

#sidebar .member {
    height: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    vertical-align: center;
}

#sidebar .member .name {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#sidebar .member .pic {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#sidebar .member .skills {
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I've put it up on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CYFyx/2/

As you can see, the elements within the `.member` element push to the top. I need them vertically aligned like so:

[image]

Already tried `vertical-align: middle;` but with no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `vertical-align: middle` in td table layout only. So you have to add a div around the spans

```
<div class="cell">
    <span class="name"><a href="">John Smith</a></span>
    <span class="skills">PHP, MySQL, Javascript, C#, Java</span>
</div>
```

with this properties

```
#sidebar .member .cell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 50px;
}
```

You can test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Tn2RU/

Comment: Best solution. This means I can have a text that wraps around to the next line and still have it float in the middle. Thanks!

Comment: `vertical-align: middle` is not reserved for 'display: table-cell` (or td). The meaning is just different in other contexts. It has a different meaning for inline elements, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting them all in a div that you can vertically align using

```
position:relative; 
margin-top: auto; 
margin-bottom: auto; 
height: XXpx;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the width of a parent element and width of your children so they must go into next line.

The other posibility would be to set your parent element to `position:relative` and then use `position:absolute` on all children and simply, precisely position them with `top:20px;` , then next one `top:40px;` etc etc.

With this second solution you can get exact pixel positioning of all children elements.

That shall positively give you best results.

Answer (score 1):

You could also put them into a div and add padding to the top.

HTML

```
<div id="block">
        <span class="name"><a href="">John Smith</a></span>
        <span class="skills">PHP, MySQL, Javascript, C#, Java</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#block {
 padding-top:5px;  
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xcMRZ/)